# Fluxcd cli autocomplete kubernetes

Tags: autocomplete, fluxcd

Is it possible to have the fluxcd cli autocomplete information from the cluster in the current context, similar to how `kubectl` or `helm` does?

While flux does provide cli completion via `flux completion SHELL`, this is only for the flux components for commands. For instance

```
flux reconcile hr -n some_namespace_start TAB
```

does not produce a suggestion on namespace. Similar issue with resource name, eg:

```
flux reconcile hr BEGIN_SOME_HR_NAME TAB
```

does not provide suggestions for helm releases in the flux-system namespace for instance.

Answer (score 0):

The auto-complete does provide completion of information from the Kubernetes cluster.

Did you load the feature as per the official documentation?

```
To load completion run

. <(flux completion bash)

To configure your bash shell to load completions for each session add to your bashrc

# ~/.bashrc or ~/.profile
command -v flux >/dev/null && . <(flux completion bash)
```

Source: https://fluxcd.io/docs/cmd/flux_completion_bash/

Please note that ZSH and FISH support are slightly different:

- https://fluxcd.io/docs/cmd/flux_completion_zsh/
- https://fluxcd.io/docs/cmd/flux_completion_fish/